# How to delete a row in java using hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm developing a product with spring mvc and hibernate, In a part i need to delete some table row. I can't find a way to do this.
I received a product name in my method and then i have to delete the product row. How can i do this?

Here is the database DB and table product:

```
create database DB;

create table DB.product (
    name varchar(255),
    price int
);

insert into DB.product values("procuct1", 100);
insert into DB.product values("procuct2", 200);
insert into DB.product values("procuct3", 300);
insert into DB.product values("procuct4", 400);
```

Also i have a method

```
public boolean deleteProduct(String productName) {
    //Now how to delete the product using hibernate
    //like "delete from DB.product where name=productName"
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below hql query:

```
String hql = "delete from product where name= :name";
session.createQuery(hql).setString("name", productName).executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helps me out.